# Pythonic way to loop over an array starting from i while maintaining the original array's indexes

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I want something like the below code, except the original list's indexes need to be maintained. So for example if i is 5 and the array had 10 elements j will be equal to 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. The below code is not doing that.

```
for j, compare in enumerate(array[i:]):                       
    #do stuff
```

Now I can do this in a more C/Java way of doing it, but is there a more pythonic way?

SOLUTION:
Thanks to [cricket-007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/cricket-007) and [zamuz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5589510/zamuz) for the help.

What I originally had is fine, but it can also be done via enumerate. @cricket-007 suggests if only the index is needed go for the original and if the value is needed also, go for enumeration.

Original:

```
for j in range(i, len(array)):
    # do stuff
```

Enumerate:

```
for j, compare in enumerate(array[i:], i):
    #do stuff
```

Comment: What you are getting out from this code snippet. I don't see any problem here

Comment: @AlokThakur j starts at zero, he wants it to start at 5 (original indexes)

Comment: [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) can start from an arbitrary number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

```
i = 5
for j in range(i, len(array)):
    # do stuff
```

Comment: Well yes, that's what I had before. However, I was watching a talk by one of the python core developers Raymon H about python idioms and one of the things he said was that this was not good python code and enumerate should be used instead.

If it can't be done in this case however, then yes. This is exactly what I want.

Comment: Which would you suggest is a better choice?

Comment: It's a preference. Use enumerate if you need both the index and the object. Otherwise, use range if you just want the numbers

Comment: OK thanks a lot. I need to use both, so I guess I will go with enumerate.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
for i, compare in enumerate(array[i:], i):
    #do stuff
```

Comment: Perfect! I mean it works. Now the question is, is this better or is what cricket_007 said better?

Comment: Might not want to use the same variable names between the loop and the parameters

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that.

Comment: I think mine is more idiomatic.

@cricket_007, you're correct.